# Java generics to simplify method calls

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

I am working on a little project that involves making some service calls to the correct service method with the corresponding data. I've attempted to solve it using the following toy problem/solution but my knowledge of generics is a bit weak and it doesnt quite work:

```
interface Handler<T>
    {
        Collection<T> apply(@Nonnull User user, @Nonnull Collection<T> data);
    }

    private static final Map<Type, Handler> HANDLERS = ImmutableMap.<Type, Handler>builder()
        .put(Type.STUDENTS, (user, data) -> Service.saveStudents(user, data))
        .put(Type.TEACHERS, (user, data) -> Service.saveTeachers(user, data))
        .put(Type.CLASSROOM, (user, data) -> Service.saveClassrooms(user, data))
        .build();

    public class Service {
        Collection<Student> saveStudents(User user, Collection<Student> students);
        Collection<Teacher> saveTeachers(User user, Collection<Teacher> teachers);
        Collection<Classroom> saveClassRooms(User user, Collection<Classroom> classrooms);
    }

    class Teacher {
        int id;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int salary;
        ...
    }

    class Student {
        int id;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int grade;
        ...
    }

    class Classroom {
        int id;
        int floor;
        ...
    }

class Payload<T> {
    Type type;
    Collection<T> dataToBeSaved;
}
```

Basically, given the above context, I have three types of objects that I try to send to my service. They dont really share common fields (across all three disregarding id). I am trying to do the following: For each payload I receive, write it to the service and print it to the console. In the end I want to get this:

```
if (payload.type.equals(Type.STUDENTS)) {
   Collection<Students> studentsWrittenToService = HANDLERS.get(type).apply(user, payload.data);
}
```

On the above lines, I get compiler warnings about HANDLERS.get(..) has raw type so result is erased. Can anyone please guide me to a solution?

Comment: The compiler is right in warning you, your types *are* broken, as the `Handler.apply` signature is `(User,T) -> Collection<T>` whereas your save methods have the signature `(User,Collection<T>) -> Collection<T>`, which does not match, but using the *raw type* `Handler` hides this.

Comment: @Holger fixed that typo, same errors though

Comment: Well, the warning tells you that the compiler is unable to recognize such errors; the fact that you really had such an error was a good example, but fixing the error doesn’t change the fact that the compiler can’t recognize whether there are such errors, so the warnings remain. I’m afraid, there is no type safe way for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`HANDLERS` is a collection of `Handler` (isn't it?)
Therefore the compiler cannot guess which generic implementation will return from call to `get()`.

You have to change the method signature so that the variable, you assign the result to controls the generic:

```
interface Handler<T>
{
   <R> R apply(@Nonnull User user, @Nonnull T data); 
}
```

Comment: Why would that be any different than just having the same T as defined in the question? Also, I think one of the problems I am having is in this snippet: private static final Map<Type, Handler> HANDLERS. The Handler doesnt have any type info

Comment: @JohnBaum you cannot specify the generic there because the you map can hole one handler type vanishing the whole purpose of the map...

Comment: With your code and what I had before, I get a compilation error on each line with "Target method is generic"

Comment: It was *your* choice to use the same type for the return value and the parameter...

Comment: Ok I think I now understand the purpose of the extra R parameter. I'm still experiencing the compilation error in the above comment though. Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: Besides the fact that this doesn’t solve the OP’s issue, it’s a pointless signature, as it allows the caller to assume an arbitrary return type while the implementation has no chance to deliver the unknown expected type. That’s like have no generic type checking at all.

Comment: @Holger *"Besides the fact that this doesn’t solve the OP’s issue"* Did I miss the comment where the OP stated that? And where is *your* suggestion? If you have none: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect

Comment: The OP’s issue is that the handlers in the `HANDLERS` map have a raw type and there is no way to store differently typed instances in the same map. Adding another type parameter to the method doesn’t help at all, as calling a generic method on a raw type is still an unchecked operation. Besides that, the OP said [With your code and what I had before, I get a compilation error on each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536659/java-generics-to-simplify-method-calls/44536821?noredirect=1#comment76064641_44536821) and “I'm still experiencing the compilation error” in another comment.